# Issue with Unity Update Loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was playing a little in Unity on a project and I stumbled upon an issue I can't address. Please keep in mind I am a beginner, and my understanding of Unity is fairly limited.
So the issue is this..
I wanted to test some if statement that went like this:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (isRow1Good() || isRow2Good() || isRow3Good() || isRow4Good() || isRow5Good() ||
            isRow6Good() || isRow7Good() || isRow8Good() || isRow9Good() || isRow10Good())
        {
            Debug.Log("LOL");
        }
    }
```

The content of the functions is this:

```
Piece p1 = row1[0].ReturnPiece();
Piece p2 = row1[1].ReturnPiece();
Piece p3 = row1[2].ReturnPiece();
Piece p4 = row1[3].ReturnPiece();
if (p1.isTall && p2.isTall && p3.isTall && p4.isTall)
{
    return true;
}


else if (p1.isRed && p2.isRed && p3.isRed && p4.isRed)
{
    return true;
}


else if (p1.isHollow && p2.isHollow && p3.isHollow && p4.isHollow)
{
    return true;
}


else if (p1.isCylinder && p2.isCylinder && p3.isCylinder && p4.isCylinder)
{
    return true;
}

else
{
    return false;
}
```

And the others are the same, just instead of row1[] it's row2[].
If the first function is true, the console logs the "LOL" message, but if the second or the third and so on are true, the value is not getting outputted. I tried changing the functions' places, every time it only cares if the first one is true, and the rest are ignored.
What would you say I am doing wrong? :D

Comment: I wonder if you have a thread that is dying because of an error in the first method in the case that it's not true.  To debug this I'd evaluate all of the methods before the if statement (something like `bool test1 = isRow1Good()`) then put the bools in the if statement.  Then do a step by step debug.

Comment: I just tried what you said. Basically ,whenever the function is not the first in the if statement, it returns false even if it should return true. Why would the order in which i put them in the if statement matter?

Comment: They are evaluated in the order that they appear.  Perhaps you should show us the code of your methods.  Perhaps one method is affecting the result of another.

Comment: I updated the content of the functions in the description.

Comment: So, ignoring the if statement, did you try assigning each method to a bool (like I described in my first comment)?  Are the values of the bools as expected?

Comment: Yes, the value of the bools are as expected. Its like the if statement is negating them. I am not sure what I did wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213880/discussion-between-alex-and-mikeh).

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (p1.isRed && p2.isRed && p3.isRed && p4.isRed)
{
    return true;
}


else if (p1.isHollow && p2.isHollow && p3.isHollow && p4.isHollow)
{
    return true;
}


else if (p1.isCylinder && p2.isCylinder && p3.isCylinder && p4.isCylinder)
{
    return true;
}
```

if I'm understanding you correct if all four pieces in a row are red its not returning true. You need to double check if the 'isRed' is set properly. if p1.isRed and p2.isRed and p3.isRed and p4.isRed then it will return true no matter what. Also double check if you meant to put || instead of &&.